# I found an Autocomplete plugin on the web but I do not understand how to implement it in my template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-forms

Can you help me with this plugin :
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-Combo-Box-Typeahead-Plugin-jQuery.html

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I already put the plugin in my static folder.

I tried to put an id to my select field but it doesn't worked.

forms.py

```py
class IndividuForm(forms.Form):
    individu = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Individu.objects.order_by('nom'), empty_label="")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IndividuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['individu'].widget.attrs={'class': 'combobox','id':'mySelect'}
```

The script

```html
<script>
   $('.mySelect').combobox()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see the field you want to target is:

```html
<select class="combobox" id="mySelect"></select>
```

But your jQuery is targetting

```html
<select class="mySelect"></select>
```

,
To target the right element you should use:

```
$('#mySelect').combobox()
```

Also make sure jQuery is called prior to combobox on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried what you said but the bootstrap-combobox.js is not loaded in my app. I do not understand why.

Comment: make sure `<script src="bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>` is included in the `<head>` of your page. You can check if the file is included in the dev tools of your browser ( under `sources` in Chrome and `Debugger` in Firefox)

Comment: I put href instead of src and now the file is loaded but I have an error ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Zapoux make sure to include jQuery before combobox and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I solved my problem. Indeed, the files were not in the right order and above all, I forgot to write {% static ... %} before including my files.

Answer (score 0):

for me, ive never heard about combo box before, i maybe getting older :)

but what you need to do is a ver easy.
just give variable a function in jquery

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  alert( "Do whatever u want");
});
```